# Want to replace multiple occurances of # to //

Tags: python, regex, python-re

The `transform_comments` function converts comments in a Python script into those usable by a C compiler. This means looking for text that begins with a hash mark (`#`) and replacing it with double slashes (`//`), which is the C single-line comment indicator. For the purpose of this exercise, we'll ignore the possibility of a hash mark embedded inside of a Python command, and assume that it's only used to indicate a comment. We also want to treat repetitive hash marks (`##`), (`###`), etc., as a single comment indicator, to be replaced with just (`//`) and not (`#//`) or (`//#`). Fill in the parameters of the substitution method to complete this function.

This is my try:

```
import re

def transform_comments(line_of_code):
  result = re.sub(r'###',r'//', line_of_code)
  return result

print(transform_comments("### Start of program")) 
# Should be "// Start of program"
print(transform_comments("  number = 0   ## Initialize the variable")) 
# Should be "  number = 0   // Initialize the variable"
print(transform_comments("  number += 1   # Increment the variable")) 
# Should be "  number += 1   // Increment the variable"
print(transform_comments("  return(number)")) 
# Should be "  return(number)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `*` regex operator

```
def transform_comments(line_of_code):
  result = re.sub(r'##*',r'//', line_of_code)
  return result
```

from the re library docs

> `*` Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. `ab*` will match `a`, `ab`, or `a` followed by any number of `b`s.

Comment: @H H thanks for help your solution is worked, however i have tried later with this `result = re.sub(r'\#+',r'//', line_of_code)` and this is also worked.

Answer (score 2):

We could use the `+` to indicate one or more occurrences of `#`

```
result = re.sub(r"#+",r"//",line_of_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def transform_comments(line_of_code):
    result = re.sub(r"#{1,}",r"//", line_of_code)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working:

```
result = re.sub(r"[#]+","//",line_of_code)
```

Comment: Your answer is right. Just a recommendation: try to explain a little bit more in future responses, not just a line of code

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def transform_comments(line_of_code):
  result = re.sub(r'(#*#) ',r'// ',line_of_code)
  return result
```